# Subfigure moves figures on the top of page

Tags: subfloats

I tried to put two figures in one row and I found that subfigure package could help me. 
But code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section{Example }
Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./2pol-hist}
                \caption{A gull}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./2pol-hist}
                \caption{A tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

reorganize my document, placing figures on the top of page. Why figures aren't below the section, as I specified in latex code?

Comment: figures are floating environments, so going to the top of the page is normal behaviour. If you never want a figure to float before its reference, add `\usepackage{flafter}` If you never want a figure to float out of its section add `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`

Comment: Hi Marcin [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)/ and let us know if your question is a duplicate :)

Comment: Thanks for response. It doesn't work in way I want. I want to have: 
some text

figures1 | figures2

more text

Like in: `
 \begin{document}
 \section{Ex}
 Lorem
 
 
 \begin{figure}[htb]
 \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{img}}
 \caption{caption}
 \end{figure}
 
 Lorem
 \end{document}`
With one figure it works. In my case, I want two figures in one row. Two figures in row, all placed in order I specified in code. Maybe subfigure in this case is not good solution? I'm quite new in LaTeX and I found that subfigures are recommended way, and another are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
Lorem ipsum

\begin{figure}[hbp]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./2pol-hist}
                \caption{A gull}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./2pol-hist}
                \caption{A tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You had a blank line between the `subfigure` environment so the second environment was starting a new paragraph; I removed the spurious blank line and replaced it with an `\hfill` to get some spacing between the `subfigure`s (not in this particular case, but you also need to be careful with possible spurious blank spaces). I also used `[hbp]` as placement specifier for the `figure` environment; this (in this case) prevents the floating object to appear before the section title and tries to place it where it was declared in the code or in the bottom of the page or in a float page (a dedicated page containing only floats).

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Using the `draft` class option your actual figures won't be included (you'll only see a rectangle and the name of the files); I suppressed that option from my example.

Comment: Possibly better `[hbp]`?

Comment: @egreg yes, maybe it's better. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. You read my mind, I almost asked, why figures are not included. I'm going to read article mentioned by cmhughes. This floating and positiong things for newbie are weird, I hope they will be clear.

Comment: @Marcin yes, that answer by Frank will clarify things. If you consider my answer solved your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted (in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954)); also, it you consider (after reading Frank's answer) that your question is a duplicate, please let us know so we can close it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: now it's clear, things are getting obvious, you can close my question. I'm beginner in LaTeX (2 days user) and yesterday  I had no idea where I can find solution and I were wasting time for looking for examples of side by side figures (there are such examples, but they focus directly on side by side, no floating, no positioning). I didn't see connection between floating and moving my figures on the top of page.